# Hiding input fields until selected in a dropdown?

Tags: javascript

Below is the JS I have used to, first, hide different forms that only show when selected from a dropdown. This also works for a second dropdown on one form that shows different input fields when selected. However it doesn't work for a third dropdown on another form. How do I make this last dropdown work?

I have ordered the JS and HTML in the same order (#selectForm/select form, #selectService/form1, #selectSelect/form2)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#selectForm').change(function() {
    var formID = $(this).val();
    $('form').css('display', 'none');
    $('#' + formID).css('display', 'block');
  })



$("#selectService").change(function() {
  var labelID = $(this).val();
  $('label').css('display', 'none');
  $('#' + labelID).css('display', 'block');
});

$("#selectSelect").change(function() {
  var labelID = $(this).val();
  $('label').css('display', 'none');
  $('#' + labelID).css('display', 'block');
});
 })
```

HTML

```
<select id="selectForm">
<option selected class="label">Select Service</option>
<option value="form1">Corporate</option>
<option value="form2">Commercial</option>
<option value="form3">Music Event</option>
<option value="form4">Social Event</option>
<option value="form5">Headshot</option>
<option value="form6">Personal</option>
</select>

<div class="formcontainer">
<form action="" enctype="text/plain" method="post" 
name="firstform" id="form1">

<input type="text" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Your name">

<input type="text" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Your email">

<input type="text" id="number" name="number" placeholder="Contact number">

<input type="text" id="company" name="company" 
placeholder="Company/Organisation">

<select id="selectService" name="service" onchange="Check(this.value);"> 
<option class="service">Specific Service</option>  
<option value="event">Event</option>
<option value="portrait">Business Portrait/Headshots</option>
<option value="web">Website Images</option>
<option value="other">Other</option>
</select>

<div class="event"> <label id="event"><input name="event" type="text" 
placeholder="Type of event" size="50" /> </label></div>

<div class="event"> <label id="amount"><input name="amount" type="text" 
placeholder="Estimated number of people attending" size="50" /> </label> 
</div>

<div class="event"><label id="specific"><textarea name="specific" 
placeholder="Specific people/moments you want photographed" 
style="height:50px"></textarea></label> </div>

<div class="event"><label id="venue"><textarea name="venue" 
placeholder="Venue name and address" style="height:50px"></textarea> 
</label> </div>

<div class="portrait"> <label id="subject"><textarea name="subject" 
placeholder="Who will be photographed(name/position)" style="height:50px;" 
></textarea> </label></div>

<div class="portrait"><label id="place"><textarea name="venue" 
placeholder="Venue name and address" style="height:50px"></textarea> 
</label> </div>

<div class="web"> <label id="web"><textarea name="web" placeholder="Who or 
what is required to be photographed" style="height:50px" ></textarea> 
</label></div>

<div class="other"><label id="other"><textarea name="other" 
placeholder="Please specify and give as much detail as possible" 
style="height:50px"></textarea></label>
</div>

<input type="text" id="contact" name="contact" placeholder="Best way to 
contact">
<textarea id="add" name="add" placeholder="Additional comments or detail" 
style="height:50px;" ></textarea>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">


  </form>

<form action="" enctype="text/plain" method="post" 
name="secondform" id="form2">

<input type="text" id="name2" name="name2" placeholder="Your name">

<input type="text" id="email2" name="email2" placeholder="Your email">

<input type="text" id="number2" name="number2" placeholder="Contact 
number">

<input type="text" id="company2" name="company2" 
placeholder="Company/Organisation">

<select id="selectSelect" name="select" onchange="Check(this.value);"> 
<option class="select">Select</option>  
<option value="travel">Travelling</option>
<option value="events">Event</option>
<option value="so">Special Occasion</option>
<option value="others">Other</option>
</select>


<div class="travel"> <label id="where"><textarea name="where" 
placeholder="Where/when?" style="height:50px;" ></textarea> </label></div>

<div class="travel"><label id="who"><textarea name="who" placeholder="Who 
with?" style="height:50px"></textarea></label> </div> 

<div class="events"> <label id="event2"><input name="event6" type="text" 
placeholder="Where/when?" size="50" /> </label></div>

<div class="events"> <label id="type"><input name="type" type="text" 
placeholder="Type of event" size="50" /> </label></div>

<div class="events"><label id="specs"><textarea name="specs" 
placeholder="Specific people/moments you want photographed" 
style="height:50px"></textarea></label> </div>

<div class="so"> <label id="sot"><textarea name="web" placeholder="Type of 
occasion" style="height:50px" ></textarea> </label></div>

<div class="so"> <label id="when"><textarea name="where" 
placeholder="When?" 
style="height:50px;" ></textarea> </label></div>

<div class="so"><label id="who2"><textarea name="who" placeholder="Who 
with?" style="height:50px"></textarea></label> </div> 

<div class="others"><label id="others"><textarea name="others" 
placeholder="Please specify and give as much detail as possible" 
style="height:50px"></textarea></label>
</div>

<input type="text" id="contact2" name="contact2" placeholder="Best way to 
contact">
<textarea id="add2" name="add2" placeholder="Additional comments or 
detail" style="height:50px;" ></textarea>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">


</form>
```

Comment: It's hard to help with this question without the relevant html, could you post that please.

Comment: First, add a class in all forms then apply css property to hide all of them. Next add an active class (based on the selected field option) by using JavaScript in the form to show this ba

Comment: @George sorry, I have now added the HTML

Comment: You should put all the event handlers inside the `$(document).ready(function(){` block.

Comment: @BurhanB I've now changed that above but it still doesn't make the last function work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For #selectService and #selectSelect, you should not use `$('label').css(...`. That would hide label elements for both of the dropdowns. Instead, you should group the labels using css classes and use that to hide them. i.e. `$(".selectServiceLabel').hide()`, "selectServiceLabel" would be the css class for all the labels you want to control with that drop down.

And #selectSelect does not seem to contain label ids. The values for this dropdown seem to match the css classes for the div elements. So you should use `$('.'+$(this).val()).show()`. You also need to group the div elements with the css class instead of the labels.